# Need to join 3 select queries that refers to same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am using SQL Server Express 2014 and I need to pull out the last record for few (3 for now) tags with different IDs from one table.

So far I made it but not at all. I am using

```
SELECT TOP 1 [TagItemId], [TagValue]
FROM [DB].[dbo].[Table] 
where [TagItemId] like 'Random.Int1'
order by [TagTimestamp] desc

SELECT TOP 1 [TagItemId], [TagValue]
FROM [DB].[dbo].[Table] 
where [TagItemId] like 'Random.Int2'
order by [TagTimestamp] desc

SELECT TOP 1 [TagItemId], [TagValue]
FROM [DB].[dbo].[Table] 
where [TagItemId] like 'Random.Int3'
order by [TagTimestamp] desc
```

and the result is what I need, but not exactly. I need to get the three results in single table like:

```
TagItemId TagValue
Random.Int1     55
Random.Int2     75
Random.Int3     23`
```

and not like:

```
TagItemId    TagValue
Random.Int1     55
TagItemId    TagValue
Random.Int2     75
TagItemId    TagValue
Random.Int3     23`
```

The reason is that I need to use the data for a chart.

Best regards and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using Row_Number

```
SELECT  [TagItemId],
        [TagValue]
FROM
    (
        SELECT  [TagItemId],
                [TagValue],
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [TagItemId] ORDER BY [TagTimestamp] DESC) Rn
        FROM    [DB].[dbo].[Table]
        WHERE   [TagItemId] IN ('Random.Int1','Random.Int2','Random.Int3')
    ) t
WHERE Rn = 1
```

Comment: It says Invalid colum names near the first select and incorrect syntax near keyword "WHERE" in the last line.

Comment: are you replacing `[DB].[dbo].[Table]` with your actual table name and fields?

Comment: @EmilSotirov  added a subquery alias just before the last WHERE.. that should fix the syntax error.

Comment: Yes, that fixed the syntax and now it works as intended. Thank you very much! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to accomplish this:

```
SELECT
    MT.TagItemID,
    MT.TagValue
FROM
    My_Table MT
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT TagItemID, MAX(TagTimestamp)
    FROM My_Table
    WHERE
        MT.TagItemID IN ('Random.Int1', 'Random.Int2', 'Random.Int3')
    GROUP BY TagItemID) SQ ON SQ.TagItemID = MT.TagItemID
WHERE
    MT.TagItemID IN ('Random.Int1', 'Random.Int2', 'Random.Int3')
```

Or:

```
SELECT
    MT.TagItemID,
    MT.TagValue
FROM
    My_Table MT
WHERE
    MT.TagItemID IN ('Random.Int1', 'Random.Int2', 'Random.Int3') AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM My_Table MT2 WHERE MT2.TagItemID = MT.TagItemID AND MT2.Timestamp > MT.Timestamp)
```

Or:

```
;WITH CTE_WithRowNums AS
(
    SELECT
        MT.TagItemID,
        MT.TagValue,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TagItemID ORDER BY Timestamp DESC) AS row_num
    FROM
        My_Table MT
)
SELECT
    TagItemID,
    TagValue
FROM
    CTE_WithRowNums
WHERE
    row_num = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just do a simple UNION ALL

```
select * from 
   (SELECT TOP 1 [TagItemId], [TagValue]
       FROM [DB].[dbo].[Table] 
       where [TagItemId] like 'Random.Int1'
       order by [TagTimestamp] desc )
UNION ALL
select * from 
   (SELECT TOP 1 [TagItemId], [TagValue]
       FROM [DB].[dbo].[Table] 
       where [TagItemId] like 'Random.Int2'
       order by [TagTimestamp] desc )
UNION ALL
select * from
    (SELECT TOP 1 [TagItemId], [TagValue]
       FROM [DB].[dbo].[Table] 
       where [TagItemId] like 'Random.Int3'
       order by [TagTimestamp] desc )
```

Probably crashed because each select TOP had an order by, so I "wrapped" the queries into select * so each subquery could retain its own ORDER BY clause

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.

Comment: @EmilSotirov, see revision with wrapped query.